# Pass <href> value when submit button is clicked?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

Since the default radio button doesnt allow me to style much, I want to create a "custom" radio button and pass the selected when the submit button is clicked.

### My Current code:

```
[http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/srJjo]
```

What it does is when user clicks on it, its `background` will turn **red** and a `value` will be stored with `valueRegistered` variable.

As you can see, how do I pass the varible value together with the `submit` button once clicked?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this solution,it might not be good in terms of performance.

What you can do is:

Add an input item in the `<form>` in a hidden state like this:

```
<input type="button" name="testing" hidden="hidden" value="__________"/>
```

You can set the `value` attribute of the field through `Javascript` when the relative link is clicked.

For instance:

```
if(sam button clicked)
    set `value` of `testing` = `sambutton`
else if(sam button2 clicked)
    set `value` of `testing` = `sambutton2`
else if(sam button3 clicked)
    set `value` of `testing` = `sambutton3`
```

Like this the value would be saved in the `testing` field and it could be submitted when you submit the form and the users won't even see it.

Regards,
Safeer